# Can someone help me with this python script

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi

I've been working on a rock paper scissors game against the computer on my raspberry pi. I have the [Blinkt HAT](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/blinkt) installed on it so I can show the score and play a nice animation when someone has won. Everything works fine but I want to make a nicer winning animation

This is where the problem comes in. I wanted to write a code that lights up some of the LEDS at the same time. But when I tried to make some code it didn't work. I went looking into the examples that the blinkt comes with the library and I found one example that nearly does what I needed. It is called [pulse.py](https://github.com/pimoroni/blinkt/blob/master/examples/pulse.py). But I don't understand some part of the code:

```
 def make_gaussian(fwhm):
     x = np.arange(0, blinkt.NUM_PIXELS, 1, float)
    y = x[:, np.newaxis]
    x0, y0 = 3.5, 3.5
    fwhm = fwhm
    gauss = np.exp(-4 * np.log(2) * ((x - x0) ** 2 + (y - y0) ** 2) / fwhm ** 2)
    return gauss


 while True:
    for z in list(range(1, 10)[::-1]) + list(range(1, 10)):
```

Can someone please explain me what these lines do?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick answer. I edited my question

Comment: Hello. I added the Asteriks to show which particular lines i didn't understand. They aren't in the actual code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`def make_gaussian(fwhm):`

create a function called "make_gaussian"

`y = x[:, np.newaxis]`

this is the same as

```
w = 5

e = "1234567890"

print(e[:w])
```

`fwhm = fwhm`

does nothing

`for z in list(range(1, 10)[::-1]) + list(range(1, 10)):`

for this you need to learn how loop work and range and list